# Download a small part of a WFS map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, wfs

I have a WFS layer I want to download a small excerpt from, so that I can derive data from its attributes. Currently, since the dataset is so large, I can't even open the attribute table without QGIS crashing.

How would I go about doing this?

The WFS API I'm trying to extract data from: (page in Finnish) https://vayla.fi/vaylista/aineistot/digiroad/aineisto/rajapinnat

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The QGIS attribute management is designed in such a way that with the default settings it is rather impossible to deal with the attributes of large WFS layers but fortunately there is an option to bypass the default.

First thing to do is to add the layer from this server so that QGIS will not try to read all the features. Zoom in rather close on the map **before** adding data from the WFS service and make sure to select the option "Only request features overlapping the view extent". That makes QGIS to create GetFeature requests with the BBOX of the map view.

[image]

The debugging tools show the generated WFS GetFeature requests, here is an example

https://julkinen.vayla.fi/inspirepalvelu/digiroad/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=digiroad:V_DR_NOPEUSRAJOITUS_YT&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3067&BBOX=428007.72060996922664344,6873005.04183434415608644,434697.58674436307046562,6877268.67868139687925577,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3067

So far everything is OK and the WFS service works well in QGIS if you do not zoom out too much. But if you want to open the attribute table by using the right click menu that opens from the layer list then QGIS by default wants to get all the attributes for the whole layer and you know already that it will fail because the largest feature types in this service have probably millions of features. QGIS behaves similarly with all types of vector layers. It is theoretically fine and allows users to search, filter, and edit attribute data also beyond the visible part of the map. However, with large datasets this strategy does not work.

Fortunately there is another way to open the attribute table through the Layer tab of the main menu.

[image]

With this option QGIS shows the attributes only for the features which are already loaded from WFS and which are visible on the map instead of trying to load the whole WFS feature type into the attribute table.

**EDIT**

It is also possible to change the default filtering of the attribute table from the settings.

[image]

Comment: For whatever reason, I don't have that option in that dropdown menu. Do I need to enable it somewhere?

Comment: I don't know. I have QGIS 3.24 and I was happy to find that option. But it is also possible to adjust the default filter and that should affect also the Right click - Open attribute layer. There is a menu for changing the filter options also in the lower left corner of the attribute table but it is not usable if the table never opens.

Comment: Ah yes it must be a new feature then. I'm on QGIS 3.22.5 (LTR). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can load the wfs service in QGIS and select a area and save the area as shap/geopackage.

Steps:
Add Layer:

1. Open QGIS-->Layer-->Add Layer-->Add WFS Layer
2. In the left pane, select "WFC/ OGC API Features"
3. Click Add, and add wfs url- https://julkinen.vayla.fi/inspirepalvelu/digiroad/wms?request=getcapabilities
   CLick "OK" to save
4. Click connect to load layer in QGIS.
5. When WFS loading is completed, Click "Edit" Menu in the top and click "Select" --> "Select Features"
6. Draw a Square on the canvas and select the features you want to save.
7. In the left pane where the wfs name is displayed, right click and select  "Export"--> "Save Selected Features AS" and save the features.

Comment: This method works as long as the data provider allows saving the data locally. If it is restricted, it will not work - just to draw the attention on this for cases where it does not work.